# Android: programatically registering Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i have a BroadcastReceiver which worked fine when i made it a seperate class and registered it in the Manifest. However, i need it as an inner class, because i want to refresh parts of the UI if the app is in the foreground and for that i have to register it programatically (because in order to register it in the Manifest file, it has to be static and therefor cant access non static outer class methods).

I am trying to do it like this, but it just does nothing (i change the hour and minutes for test purposes)

```
registerReceiver(new DayCheckReceiver(), new IntentFilter());

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
dayCheckIntent = new Intent(this, DayCheckReceiver.class);

dayCheckAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2000000000, dayCheckIntent, 0); // i use this high number because i use 1+ for a growing list
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 19);
if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), dayCheckAlarmIntent);
```

This is the BroadcastReceiver as an inner Class:

```
public class DayCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //load
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TASKLIST_FILE, null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TaskItem>>() {
        }.getType();
        mTaskList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        //modifications
        if (mTaskList != null && mTaskList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTaskList.size(); i++) {
                mTaskList.get(i).shiftDayChecks();
                mTaskList.get(i).resetTimeLeft();
            }
        }

        //save
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        gson = new Gson();
        json = gson.toJson(mTaskList);
        editor.putString(TASKLIST_FILE, json);
        editor.apply();

        tasksFragment.loadTaskList();
        tasksFragment.updateTaskList();
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty `IntentFilter`? I never tried it like this, but I don't think that this works. With broadcasts you usually filter on an action and pass that same action as a parameter to the constructor of both the filter and intent

Comment: Well, when i had it registered in manifext.xml, it worked without an intent filter. Can you tell me what i would put in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your register line.

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(action));
```

where `mReceiver` is the object of BroadcastReceiver and `action` is a String for which BroadcastReceiver will be listening.

Then inside BroadcastReceiver you need to check the action before doing anything else.

```
public static final String CONSTANT_ACTION = "broadcast_action";

mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (null != intent && CONSTANT_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))
                // Write your code here
        }
    };
```

And this is how you broadcast the event

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CONSTANT_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I get 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=DAY_CHECK_ACTION flg=0x10 }
i also dont understand where i reference to the correct broadcast class if i just put that constant into new Intent

Comment: I now realized where the error came from: From calling the method that should update the UI. The registering of the broadcast is working, but there is a problem with putting that method in there. I will probably figure that out.

Comment: @Fr4nkWh1te Do not forget to unregister the BroadcastReceiver when activity is destroyed.

Comment: Even if I want it to run when the app is not running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some action in your intentfilter, say `new IntentFilter("Alarm")`. You will also use the same action when sending a broadcast using `sendBroadcast(new Intent("Alarm"))`

Comment: Hey, i tried changing it, but i get : Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=DAY_CHECK_ACTION flg=0x10 }
Any idea?

Comment: I now realized where the error came from: From calling the method that should update the UI. The registering of the broadcast is working, but there is a problem with putting that method in there. I will probably figure that out.